# Implementing MSSCCI providers in .Net

Tags: .net, msscci

I would like to implement a MSSCCI provider, however if at all possible I would like to implement it in .Net (so my MSSCCI provider is in fact a thin wrapper around a .Net implementation)

- Is this possible?
- Is this a good idea?

I know that implementing it in .Net would mean that anyone using my MSSCCI provider would be forced to host the .Net framework inside their process - is this an unreasonable request?  Also what other limitations would I need to consider if I were to implement it in .Net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible, and relatively easy. I developed one some time ago and it works fine. I used COM interoperability from **C++** to **C#**.

So, you will create two dlls. The **C++** one is only a wrapper that implements the API pass the calls to a **COM** in **C#**. The C# one must be registered as a **COM** component with regasm /codebase mycomlibrary.dll

Here are some guidelines to implement it. In the code sample I only implement the `SccInitialize` function as an example. Hope it helps.

This is the **C++** component:

```
#include <comutil.h>

/**********************************************************************************************************/
// Imports the COM object that implements the SCC API in .NET
/**********************************************************************************************************/
#import "SccCOMServer.tlb" no_namespace named_guids

static int s_nInitializedCount = 0;

/**********************************************************************************************************/
// Starting point of the dll
/**********************************************************************************************************/
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( 
                      HANDLE hModule, 
                      DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                      LPVOID lpReserved
                      )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

/**********************************************************************************************************/
// Variable with a instance of the COM object
/**********************************************************************************************************/

ISccCOMServer *mCpi = NULL;


/**********************************************************************************************************/
// Utility functions
/**********************************************************************************************************/

void BSTR2T(BSTR s1, LPSTR s2)
{
    _bstr_t s(s1, false);
    strcpy(s2, s);
}

char* ConvertBSTRToLPSTR (BSTR bstrIn)
{
    LPSTR pszOut = NULL;
    if (bstrIn != NULL)
    {
        int nInputStrLen = SysStringLen (bstrIn);

        // Double NULL Termination
        int nOutputStrLen = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, bstrIn, nInputStrLen, NULL, 0, 0, 0) + 2; 
        pszOut = new char [nOutputStrLen];

        if (pszOut)
        {
            memset (pszOut, 0x00, sizeof (char)*nOutputStrLen);
            WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, 0, bstrIn, nInputStrLen, pszOut, nOutputStrLen, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    return pszOut;
}

 /**********************************************************************************************************/
//                                      IMPLEMENTATION OF THE FUNCTIONS
/**********************************************************************************************************/


/**********************************************************************************************************/
// Initialization and Housekeepeng Functions
/**********************************************************************************************************/

SCCEXTERNC SCCRTN EXTFUN __cdecl SccInitialize(
    LPVOID * ppContext, 
    HWND hWnd, 
    LPCSTR lpCallerName,
    LPSTR lpSccName, // [In, out]
    LPLONG lpSccCaps, // [Out]
    LPSTR lpAuxPathLabel, // [In, out]
    LPLONG pnCheckoutCommentLen, // [Out]
    LPLONG pnCommentLen //[Out]
    )
{

    // Initialize COM the first time the function is called
    CoInitialize(0);
    s_nInitializedCount++;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ISccCOMServerImpl,
        NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_ISccCOMServer, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&mCpi));

    long response;

    // We need auxiliar strings because out string in COM are BSTR *  
    BSTR bstrSccName;
    BSTR bstrAuxPathLabel;

    bstrSccName = T2BSTR(lpSccName);
    bstrAuxPathLabel = T2BSTR(lpAuxPathLabel);

    Context *CC = new Context;
    // Calling to the COM equivalent Function

    response = mCpi->Initialize(CC, (long) hWnd, lpCallerName, &bstrSccName, lpSccCaps, &bstrAuxPathLabel, 
        pnCheckoutCommentLen, pnCommentLen);

    *ppContext = (void *)CC;

    // Converting the strings
    BSTR2T(bstrSccName, lpSccName);
    BSTR2T(bstrAuxPathLabel, lpAuxPathLabel);
    return response;

}
```

And then the **C#** part is simpler:

```
[Guid("C6659361-1625-4746-931C-36014B146679")]
public class ISccCOMServerImpl : ISccCOMServer
{
    public int Initialize(
        out Context ppContext,
        IntPtr hWnd,
        string lpCallerName,
        ref string lpSccName, // out
        out int lpSccCaps, // out
        ref string lpAuxPathLabel, // out
        out int pnCheckoutCommentLen, // out
        out int pnCommentLen //out
        )
    {
       //your manage code here!
    }
```

}